# Mac System name

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a program in python that uses commands and files that are os dependent and I don't have access to a mac. What is the exact system name for the `os.name()` command?

Better yet what is the `platform.system()` answer. I have windows which of course is 'windows' and I have Linux which in my case is 'Linux' but what is mac? So right now I need the output for os.name() and platform.system(). Preferably a more recent version of OS X like either mountain lion or Maverick.

Comment: I think Martijn's answer is exactly what you want. But if you need a specific recent version of OS X, check [`platform.mac_ver`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.mac_ver). `platform.mac_ver()[0]` will be the release number (e.g., `'10.9'`), which you can parse and compare. (Just don't compare it as a string, or your code will tell everyone running Yosemite that they need at least 10.8…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The platform name for *all* OS X releases is `Darwin`:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Apr 28 2014, 17:17:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Darwin'
```

`platform.system()` uses `os.uname()`, and you can look up responses on the [uname Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname).